# How to select multiple date in calendar and display it in label

Tags: asp.net, calendar

Suppose I have Calender and and I want to select multiple date and display in label.
I have use following code but it is not working properly. Please correct it

```
lblMultipleDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDates[0].ToShortDateString();
Label2.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDates[Calendar1.SelectedDates.Count-1].ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link on how to select multiple dates in Calendar control:

[Calendar control with multiple date selections](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/03/09/tiptrick-aspnet-calendar-control-with-multiple-date-selections.aspx)

Hopefully, it helps.

Comment: dead link, and this is why it is suggested to never answer with only a link

Comment: @peroija, thanks for the tip. Just tried the link, and it works.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaand its back up. Apparently I had clicked it when the host's 99.99% uptime failed :P