# load an array of dates from web service to asp.net calendar control

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar

I am calling a web service using a service reference in c# and have collected a list of date strings (collection dates) into an array list in a public class

public  List DateList { get; set; }

I now want to load the dates into asp.net calendar so users can see what dates are available each month.

This should be simple but I am having trouble finding a way to do this? is it possible

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried so far for loading dates in asp.net calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to highlight some of the dates of the calendar control you may have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9782434/6578055). You can convert your list `public List DateList { get; set; }` to `public static List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();` and create a method that will render the control with the highlighted dates. This article provides the complete implementation [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/03/09/tiptrick-aspnet-calendar-control-with-multiple-date-selections.aspx). Sample code used in the article.
  `if (Session["SelectedDates"] != null)
        {
            List<DateTime> newList = (List<DateTime>)Session["SelectedDates"];
            foreach (DateTime dt in newList)
            {
                Response.Write(dt.ToShortDateString() + "<BR/>");
            }
        }`

Comment: That looks exactly what I am trying to do. Cheers for that.